# How to install Bugzilla in Solaris 10 server?

Tags: bugzilla

how to install Bugzilla in Solaris 10 server?

Is there any step by step guide?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found that:

- [The Bugzilla Guide > Chapter 4. Installation > 4.1. Step-by-step Install](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/2.16/html/stepbystep.html): not specifically for Solaris 10
- [Bugzilla on Solaris Operating Environment](http://www.nbl.fi/~nbl97/solaris/web/bugzilla.html): for Solaris 10